# Should department filter be located to the left or the right of the search text input in e-commerce sites?

Tags: search, filter, input-fields

I'm working on a new shopping site and i see a possible minor improvement.

We have a typical search form on top left, with dropdown for categories and input field.

I think maybe it's better if we switch the input text for the dropdown.

If you can help me explain the improvement (if there is any)...
I think when we seek for the search form, it will be better to have right there the input and then the dropdown.

Here's the current form:

[image]

Comment: Interestingly Amazon and newegg do this with the dropdown first, ebay and others do it on the right. I'm not seeing a clear trend either way. As long as they don't have to interact with the drop down I bet users' eyes often just zip straight to the input field

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to say which positioning is the right one. As you can see from the examples below, there's no uniformity among US online retailers.

Do an A/B test measuring how many people use the initial department filter and what they do after (apply more filters or start browsing the results & adding them to carts). Then you'll know what works best for your customers.

Amazon (new white theme)
[image: amazon search filter]

Buy.com
[image: buy.com search filter]

Kmart
[image: kmart search filter]

NewEgg
[image: newegg search filter]

Walmart
[image: walmart search filter]